# AWS EBS - Rails5 / nginx - robots.txt not found error (404)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, robots.txt, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed a pretty standard Rails 5 app with AWS EBS.
My `/robots.txt` is not reacheable and requests to it's URL return a 404 error.

I put it in the `/public` folder along with `404.html`, `422.html` and `500.html` pages, which are correctly served by nginx.

Any clue about what might be wrong? What shall I check?

`EB CLI 3.14.6 (Python 2.7.1)`

`Ruby 2.4.3 / Rails 5.1.4 / Puma (gem) 3.7`

Comment: is there a URL to a reference implementation?  We would be happy to verify from our side and help walk you through any issues.  Without any code or repo, we cant help you much.

Comment: Sure.. i just didn't want to publicize my app. It's aparcagratis.com

Comment: Are you deploying via macOS or Linux and cli?  Or via console?

Comment: Via the cli in macosx, eb deploy does the trick

Comment: Ok I’ll try one similar tonight from my Mac to reproduce.  If you can post the version numbers of your cli that would help

Comment: Hi, it's `EB CLI 3.14.6 (Python 2.7.1)`

Comment: what version of Ruby / Rails / Puma ?

Comment: Ruby 2.4.3 / Rails 5.1.4 / Puma (gem) 3.7

Comment: Hi @Taterhead, did you have any luck with it?

Comment: Sorry - my free time has been overtaken by events.  Im encouraged by the potential that the new guy at AWS will help, especially with workaround 2.  A quick google found this article:  https://medium.com/@marilu597/getting-to-know-and-love-aws-elastic-beanstalk-configuration-files-ebextensions-9a4502a26e3c - If I get time, Ill try and revisit to write one also.  This should not be too difficult.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a very similar question have been asked *4 years ago* on the official AWS forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=150904

Only 4 years later a brave guy from AWS stepped in with a reply! Here below the quoted reply:

> Hello hello! I'm Chris, the new Ruby platforms person at Elastic
>   Beanstalk. Visiting this thread today, it looks like there's been a
>   lot of pain (and also confusion!) from Beanstalk's Ruby+Puma's
>   handling of static files.
>
> Quick summary: When this thread was created (in 2014), Beanstalk was
>   essentially using the default Nginx that comes with Amazon Linux, with
>   only some logging modifications to support the health monitoring. That
>   spawned this thread, as static files are generally expected to be
>   served the the web server when one is present.
>
> So, the folks here went and fixed the /assets folder. Great!
>   Unfortunately, there was a misunderstanding with the request to fix
>   serving the /public folder - Beanstalk's Puma platform instead serves
>   things in '/public' from '/pubilc', not from '/'. This is definitely
>   an issue, so here's some workarounds:
>
> Workaround 1: Turning on serve static assets. Yes, this wastes some
>   application threads here or there, but if your use case is only
>   robots.txt and favicon.ico, you're only robbing a couple of appserver
>   threads. I'd pick this one unless I was running my application servers
>   hot.
>
> Workaround 2: Write an .ebextension to modify the Nginx configuration
>   to serve /public at /. I'm in the process of writing one, so I'll tack
>   it as a reply to this when I've given it the thought it deserves. Some
>   of the current ones may serve your app's code, so double check the
>   configuration if you've already done this workaround.
>
> I've created a tracking issue for the team with this level of detail,
>   so we'll work to get this corrected. Thank you all for your feedback -
>   we'd love to serve you and your apps better.

Since then, no further replies; if anybody knows the "aws-approved-way" to edit nginx config with .ebextensions let's post it here please! :)

Answer (score 2):

In AWS EB with PUMA, static files under the public folder are served under the /public/ url. Webcrawlers expect the file available at /robots.txt

I've struggled to try and implement routing to these files and settled instead on a more 'Rails' way of implementing this.

**1) config/routes.rb**

```
get "/robots.txt", to: "robots#show"
```

**2) app/controllers/robots_controller.rb**

```
class RobotsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render "show", layout: false, content_type: "text/plain"
  end 
end
```

**3) app/views/robots_txts/show.erb**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 2):

The above link to AWS forums is erroring with a 400 right now, so here's how I fixed this issue.  Ruby 2.7 running on AWS2 platform:

**Static Files in sub-directory of `/public`:**

Create a file under the `.ebextensions` folder called `static-files.conf`.  Content should look similar to:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /w3c: public/w3c
    /images: public/images
```

This will ensure that all requests to `domain.com/images` and `domain.com/w3c` are served from the appropriate `/public` sub-directory.

**Static Files in top level of `/public` directory:**
For top-level files like `robots.txt` or `sitemap.xml` add appropriate entry to `routes.rb` to serve the static content directly:

```rb
  get '/robots.txt', to: proc {|env| [200, {}, [File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'robots.txt')).read]] }
  get '/sitemap.xml', to: proc {|env| [200, {}, [File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'sitemap.xml')).read]] }
```

**Ensure `production.rb` has static files config set properly:**

```rb
config.serve_static_files = false
```

This last part is most-important.